# Fading bug with image uploader

Tags: bug, uploader

If I open the image uploader, the background goes darker.

Compare:

[image]

[image]

Now that is by design, and if or click outside the upload box, the box goes, and the background disappears.

However, if you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, only the box goes - the background stays the same. I think this is a recent bug - I always used to use <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and it worked perfectly.

Chrome 39.0.2171.95 on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox 34.0.5 on a Windows 7.